# SandBoxed Solution - Assembly Missing

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution

We have a sandboxed solution on a site collection. It is activated, and it has a custom assembly. This assembly is inside "C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\SharePoint\UCCache" as described in the documentation.

But, we have some errors in ULS which indicate the process cannot find/locate the assembly. Have we missed something?

We took a look between the assembly inside "UCCache" and the error, and the signature is the same (ie publickeytoken, version and name).

Thanks for your help